# Powershell - Fastest way to create a very large array of hashtables

Tags: arrays, performance, powershell, optimization, hashtable

I am trying to create a rather large array of hashtables, with much of the data either fully randomized or randomly picked from a list.

Here is my **Current Code**

```bsh
    $ArrayData = @()
    $ArrayDataRows = 150000

    foreach ($i in 1..$ArrayDataRows) {

        $thisobject = [PSCustomObject] @{
            Number = $i
            Place = Get-Random -InputObject NJ, UT, NY, MI, PA, FL, AL, NM, CA, OK, TX, CO, AZ
            Color = Get-Random -InputObject red, yellow, blue, purple, green, white, black
            Zone = (Get-Random -InputObject $([char[]](65..90)) -Count 10) -join ""
            Group = Get-Random -InputObject @(1..20)
        }


        $ArrayData += $thisobject 
     }
```

What I notice though, is that it seems to not be efficient. It takes 25 mins in total to finish for 150k rows.

I had some additional code not posted here which measured how long it took each instance and estimated the average from it to its predecessors. Initially, it would give me an estimate for 450 secs for the total and 0.002 as an Average per instance for the first 3k items but later it just kept slowly crawling up to 0.016 or 8 times slower as an average.

How can I optimize and/or make this more efficient while achieving the same data as a result?

Comment: IIRC, your `@()` is making a new copy every time you `+=`.  Use `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` and `.Add()` and I'll bet your perf goes up.

Comment: Also, for all those InputObjects, create them once outside the loop and store in variables. Could be negligible given the small sizes, but still an optimization.

Comment: the fastest way to get things into a collection is to use `$Collection = foreach ()` ... that gathers all the items in RAM and finally stuffs _all of them at once_ into the `$Collection`. it's actually faster than the `.Add()` methods of  `ArrayList` & `Generic.List` collection types. [*grin*]

Comment: also, you are NOT making an array of hashtables ... you are making an array of PSCustomObjects. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[edit - you are NOT making an array of hashtables. you are making an array of `PSCustomObject` items. [*grin*]]*

the standard array is a *fixed size* object. take a look at `$ArrayData.IsFixedSize` for confirmation of that. [*grin*]

so, when you use `+=` on a standard array, powershell makes a NEW, one-item-larger array, copies the old one into the new one, and finally adds the new item. it's fast when the item count & size are "small", but it gets slower [and slower, and slower] as the count/size grows.

there are two common solutions ...

- use a collection type that has an `.Add()` method
  the `ArrayList` [deprecated], and the `Generic.List` are the ones folks usually use. the 1st outputs an index number when you add to it, so even if it wasn't deprecated, i would not use it. [*grin*]
- use the output stream
  you can use `$Results = foreach ($Thing in $Collection) {Do-Stuff}` and the output of the scriptblock will be held in RAM until the loop completes. then it will be stuffed into the `$Results` collection all at once.

the 2nd is the fastest.

if you have no need to change the size of the collection after you build it, then use the 2nd method. otherwise use the 1st.

as an example of the speed, your code [with 15,000 items] runs in 39 seconds on my system. using the "send to output" technique takes 24 seconds.

remember that the slow down will continue to get worse as the array gets larger. i was unwilling to wait on 150k iterations.

here's my demo code ...

```
$ArrayDataRows = 15e3
$PlaceList = 'NJ, UT, NY, MI, PA, FL, AL, NM, CA, OK, TX, CO, AZ'.Split(',').Trim()
$ColorList = 'red, yellow, blue, purple, green, white, black'.Split(',').Trim()
$UC_LetterList = [char[]](65..90)
$GroupList = 1..20

(Measure-Command -Expression {
    $ArrayData = foreach ($i in 1..$ArrayDataRows) {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Number = $i
            Place = Get-Random -InputObject $PlaceList
            Color = Get-Random -InputObject $ColorList
            Zone = -join (Get-Random -InputObject $UC_LetterList -Count 10)
            Group = Get-Random -InputObject $GroupList
            }

        }
    }).TotalMilliseconds
# total ms = 24,390
```

Comment: Do you have any references or tips on using `Generic.List`? I'd like to look into that a bit. I've started using `ArrayList` in some of my code that needs performance, and I haven't had a reason not to use it - yet. Outputting the index number, for example, isn't an issue because I always cast it into the void when I'm adding something like this: `[void]$ArrayData.Add($i)`, so any other reasons NOT to use `ArrayList` for you?

Comment: @immobile2 - the `generic.list` collection type is the one MS recommends. the `arraylist` type is deprecated - which means that it may vanish with little or no additional warning. **_it WILL vanish eventually._** ///// the _benefit_ to using the `arraylist` type is that you don't need to define the content type - it's like an array in that you can stuff almost anything into it. _that is also one of its disadvantages._ the `generic.list` content type MUST be defined - and that can be useful when type enforcement is useful. you can always sidestep the type by using `[PSObject]`.[*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

[Lee_Daily's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55466198/45375) discusses important **general optimization techniques with respect to building arrays (collections)**.

Another important piece to the puzzle is to **avoid (multiple) cmdlet calls inside  a loop**, if possible.

Replacing the `Get-Random` calls with use of `[random]` ([`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random)) provides the largest speedup (PSv5+ syntax):

```
$ArrayDataRows = 150000

$places = 'NJ', 'UT', 'NY', 'MI', 'PA', 'FL', 'AL', 'NM', 'CA', 'OK', 'TX', 'CO', 'AZ'
$colors = 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'white', 'black'
$chars = [char[]] (65..90)
$nums = 1..20

# Instantiate a random number generator.
$rndGen = [random]::new()

$ArrayData = foreach ($i in 1..$ArrayDataRows) {
  [PSCustomObject] @{
     Number = $i
     Place = $places[$rndGen.Next(0, $places.Count)]
     Color = $colors[$rndGen.Next(0, $colors.Count)]
     Zone = -join $(
         $charList = [Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new($chars)
         foreach ($n in 1..10) { $randIndex = $rndGen.next(0, $charList.count); $charList[$randIndex]; $charList.RemoveAt($randIndex) }
       )
     Group = $nums[$rndGen.Next(0, $nums.Count)]
 }
```

On my machine, the above takes about 12 seconds, whereas your original command ran for about 35 minutes(!), which **amounts to a speedup factor of about 175**.

---

**Benchmarks**:

The following are sample timings that contrast your original approach, Lee's optimized version of it, and the `[random]`-based solution above; the absolute numbers aren't important, but the relative performance is, as shown in the `Factor` column:

With `1000` array elements:

```
Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   0.100              # with [random]…
12.78  1.273              # with Get-Random - optimized…
13.45  1.340              # with Get-Random - original approach…
```

Note that at 1000 elements the optimization of the array-building approach provides some, but not a huge speedup, but the benefit is larger the more elements there are.

With `10,000` array elements:

```
Factor Secs (10-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------ -------
1.00   1.082              # with [random]…
12.29  13.296             # with Get-Random - optimized…
20.40  22.081             # with Get-Random - original approach…
```

With 10,000 elements, the optimization of the array-building already pays off handsomely.

I didn't have the patience for running with `150,000` elements, but it's easy to adapt the following code, which uses the [`Time-Command` function](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

```
$ArrayDataRows = 1000

$places = 'NJ', 'UT', 'NY', 'MI', 'PA', 'FL', 'AL', 'NM', 'CA', 'OK', 'TX', 'CO', 'AZ'
$colors = 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'white', 'black'
$chars = [char[]] (65..90)
$nums = 1..20

Time-Command -Count 10 { # with [random]
    # Instantiate a random number generator.
    $rndGen = [random]::new()
    $ArrayData = foreach ($i in 1..$ArrayDataRows) {
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        Number = $i
        Place = $places[$rndGen.Next(0, $places.Count)]
        Color = $colors[$rndGen.Next(0, $colors.Count)]
        Zone = -join $(
            $charList = [Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new($chars)
            foreach ($n in 1..10) { $randIndex = $rndGen.next(0, $charList.count); $charList[$randIndex]; $charList.RemoveAt($randIndex) }
          )
        Group = $nums[$rndGen.Next(0, $nums.Count)]
      }
    }

  }, { # with Get-Random - optimized
    $ArrayData = foreach ($i in 1..$ArrayDataRows) {
       [PSCustomObject] @{
          Number = $i
          Place = Get-Random -InputObject $places
          Color = Get-Random -InputObject $colors
          Zone = -join (Get-Random -InputObject $chars -Count 10)
          Group = Get-Random -InputObject $nums
      }
    }
  } ,{ # with Get-Random - original approach
    $ArrayData = @()
    foreach ($i in 1..$ArrayDataRows) {
        $thisobject = [PSCustomObject] @{
            Number = $i
            Place = Get-Random -InputObject $places
            Color = Get-Random -InputObject $colors
            Zone = -join (Get-Random -InputObject $chars -Count 10)
            Group = Get-Random -InputObject $nums
        }
        $ArrayData += $thisobject 
    }
  }
```